# What is the purpose of the EOL semicolon in this bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to adapt some [code](https://github.com/codingtony/udev-monitor-hotplug/blob/master/usr/local/bin/monitor-hotplug.sh) I found for a monitor layout script.

```sh
...
while read l 
do 
  dir=$(dirname $l); 
  status=$(cat $l); 
  dev=$(echo $dir | cut -d\- -f 2-); 

  if [ $(expr match  $dev "HDMI") != "0" ]
...
```

As per the Bash man page: A semicolon can either be a metacharacter or a control operator.

I understand the metacharacter use is for consecutive commands on the same line. Is it being used as a control operator in this case? I haven't used it this way before and the script functions without it. I don't want to remove or keep it without understanding its purpose.

Comment: All 3 `;` are not required as your commands are on separate lines.

Comment: Is there no good reason for the developer adding them?

Comment: No there is no apparent good reasons for this other than being accustomed on some programming language.

Comment: Thank you, that sets my mind at ease.

Comment: I guess this was written from someone who comes from a language that needs the semicolon. Happens to me very often when going from c++ to bash :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There *might* have been some thinking process going on along the lines of

- "this should execute even if concatenated into a single line", or
- "this was *created* from a single line originally".

But in that case you would need *additional* semicolons at the end of the `while` and `if` lines to make it work.

So, **no, there is no purpose to them** other than a bad habit by the programmer in question.

Answer (score 1):

No, you will not need a semicolon in this case. You would need a semicolon in bash if there is more then one command on a single line. Here is an example of where a semicolon is often used in bash to make it more readable:

```
if [ $a -gt 12 ]; then
```

You see here, the `if` and the `then` are two different commands, but you can use the semicolon to put them on the same line, which makes the code easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, I understand its use in this case but was befuddled by its purpose EOL.

Answer (score 0):

As per @anubhava's comment on the question"

> No there is no apparent good reasons for this...